# UUID.ism not supported in streaming.media.azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I have uploaded video file which contains uuid name(uuid.mp4) and url is working fine but below trimmed uuid.ism is not working. when i rename the uuid to another simple name then it works.

Im getting below error response when using uuid.mp4. I have checked the container blob storage and uuid.mp4 file exists.

MPE_STORAGE_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

When i replace "567d8351-3512-402b-a181-df704d08123e.mp4" with some other name like "sample.mp4" then it works.

Below uuid.ism not working until i change the uuid name to some other name.

testingmedia-usea.streaming.media.azure.net/50c3729a-2be1-49df-8aec-e3f915e0ea76/567d8351-3512-402b-a181-df704d08123e.ism/manifest

I hope i get some response. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using dashes in the file name for AMS Asset should be fine; Azure Media Service has two main restrictions for the files name:

•   The value of the name property cannot have any of the following percent-encoding-reserved characters: !*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]". Also, there can only be one '.' for the file name extension.

•   The length of the name should be at most 260 characters.

In addition to the general guidelines from Azure storage ([blob name requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata) and the [NTFS name requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file))

Reference: [Assets in Azure Media Services | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/media-services/latest/assets-concept#naming-filesblobs-within-an-asset)

We did some tests by creating an asset with an mp4 file with a UUID name, and the stream is working successfully.

I suggest you do a simple test (steps below), and see how it goes.

•   Rename the MP4 file to UUID name on local machine

•   Create a new Asset and upload the UUID mp4 file

•   Encode that Asset using any transform (to generate a streaming-ready Asset)

•   Create a streaming locator, then test the streaming URL using any player or our media player demo page [Azure Media Player (azureedge.net)](https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/)

The streaming URL should be like this:
[Streaming Endpoint hostname]/[Streaming Locator ID]/{UUID}.ism/manifest

Comment: Im actually uploading the file with uuid name as you have mentioned and it didnt work thats why I posted the question here.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, just to double-confirm you had encoded the Asset after uploading the UUID.MP4 file, not only uploading a new file to an Asset already encoded. 
If you encoded the Asset and then changed the MP4 or ISM name, and then received a 404 HTTP error message, that would be expected. 

The streaming service depends on the file names generated after the encoding, so any change in any file name can lead to similar issues.

We repeated the test on our side, and the streaming worked as expected with an encoded asset that has the mp4 file name in UUID format.

Comment: Thank you for your response, The thing is, after uploading the uuid file there is a programatical extraction of the uuid name and I'm uploading the blob data with the same uuid name. after that it creates the asset and blah blah blah and then it gives me manifest url. In between I didnt change any name internally.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delay! We noticed that the name of the ISM file has only 32 characters. In contrast, the UUID name has 36 characters, so based on your workflow description, I believe that you are code building the streaming URL manually, and if that’s correct, this will explain why the streaming URL on your side does not work (return 404 HTTP status), since the used file name for the ISM is 36 chars, while, the actual one (stored on AMS) is 32 chars long, so AMS can’t find the needed file (full UUID.ism)

The best practice and the recommendation to get the streaming URL is to get the streaming URLs via AMS API/SDK function and then store it on your side.

- Samples | leverage based on your framework/use-case:

**SDK and API:**

AMS .NET SDK : [StreamingLocatorsOperationsExtensions.ListPaths Method
(Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.media.streaminglocatorsoperationsextensions.listpaths?view=azure-dotnet)

AMS API reference:  [Streaming Locators - List Paths - REST API (Azure Media Services) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/media/streaming-locators/list-paths?tabs=HTTP#list-paths-which-has-streaming-paths-and-download-paths)

**Code samples:**

.NET: [media-services-v3-dotnet/Program.cs at main · Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet · GitHub (Line 429)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/blob/main/VideoEncoding/Encoding_PredefinedPreset/Program.cs#L429)

NodeJS: [media-services-v3-node-tutorials/index.ts at main · Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials · GitHub (Line 320)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/Streaming/StreamFilesSample/index.ts#L320)